# xcode beta 2 xib view can't be referenced in the outlests

Tags: xcode, swift, xcode6

I have a nib that I have a UIView in. I can set the UIViewController just fine but right clicking and dragging from the view to the files owner doesn't allow me to connect up the view Referencing outlet. The only way it seems to work is if I use a storyboard and add a UIViewController that way.

Wonder if anyone else has this bug and has found a way around it.

Comment: Cmd+S to save any relevant files and try again.  Cmd+Shift+K to clean the project and try again.

Comment: This appears being addressed in Beta 3, reference: [Beta 4 Release Notes](http://developer.apple.com/xcode/releasenotes/prerelease/ios/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a known issue of Xcode 6 Beta 2, here is reference from [Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/releasenotes/prerelease/ios/index.html):

> If an existing outlet in a Swift ﬁle is declared to be an instance of a class that is implemented in Swift, it is not currently possible to connect an object in a .xib or .storyboard ﬁle to that outlet.
>
> Workaround: Create a new outlet by Control-dragging from the object to an empty location in the Swift class. Alternatively, change the outlet’s type to AnyObject, then Control-drag from the object to the outlet. The outlet's type can then be changed back to the correct class. (16968022)

Edit: This appears being addressed in Beta 3.

Comment: This somewhat answered my question but the solution stated in the change long on how to get outlets working didn't seem to solve the problem. The only thing it did do is stop crashing when trying to create the outlet.